# Limit points of $A=\{(x,y)\mid (x^2+y^2)(y^2-x^2+1)\le0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m having a hard time trying to figure out accumulation points in this set. I have an easy enough time with accumulation points in 1 dimension but this is really twisting my brain. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$A= \{(0,0)\} \cup A^\prime$$ where

$$A^\prime=\{(x,y)\mid y^2-x^2+1\le0\}$$

$A^\prime$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ as it is the inverse image of the closed subset $(-\infty, 0]$ under the continuous map $(x,y) \mapsto y^2-x^2+1$.

As $(0,0) \notin A^\prime$, $(0,0)$ is not a limit point of $A$.

And as $A^\prime$ is closed, the set of limit points of $A$ is included in $A^\prime$.

Now, it is fairly easy to prove that all $x \in A^\prime$ is a limit point of $A$.

Finally the set of limit points of $A$ is $A^\prime$.

Answer (score 0):

If we break apart the factors.

$(x^2+y^2) \ge 0$

The origin in the set.

Or the other factor is less than $0$

$y^2 - x^2 + 1 \le 0\\
x^2 - y^2 \ge 1$

That describes region defined by a hyperbola.